# Remove label positioned on top of textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea, label

I currently have a `label` that is absolute positioned within a textarea.

I'm trying to get the following working:

Once I click `textarea`, have the `label` disappear. Once I click outside the `textarea`, check if there's any content that I've added. If not, put the `label` back. If yes, just leave it out.

[jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/tDHwZ/2/).

I tried with `$('html').click()`, but it seems to interferes with the `textarea` click.

Comment: You should use the `placeholder` attribute, and one of the various [polyfills that are available](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want focus and blur **Working Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/tDHwZ/10/

```
 $('#comment').focus(function() {
            $(this).prev().hide()  
        });
 $('#comment').blur(function() {
            if($(this).val()=='')
           $(this).prev().show()  
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

For this situation by replacing the **.click()** event with the **.blur()** you should achieve the expected result.

You can check on the link bellow:

http://jsfiddle.net/tDHwZ/27/

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#comment').blur(function() {

        if($('#comment').val()!= "") {
           $('label[for=comment]').addClass('hidden');    
        } else {
           $('label[for=comment]').removeClass('hidden');                
        }



        if($('label[for=comment]').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('label[for=comment]').hide();

        } else {
            $('label[for=comment]').show();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using HTML5 then surely the placeholder attribute takes care of this. Or if not HTML5 then maybe this will help http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-inline-form-labels